# In MongoUri how can I handle @ in my password?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My Mongo Uri is like this. There must be an @ at the end of my password. And Mongo throws an error called= Unescaped at-sign in authority section. Is there a way to make it work?

```
 const url = 'mongodb://roots:something@@localhost:27017?authMechanism=DEFAULT&authSource=db';
```

Comment: why do you need 2x @?

Answer (score 1):

you can also encode your string using template literals like this:

const DB_USER = 'roots';

const PASSWORD = encodeURIComponent('something@');

const DB_URL = `mongodb://${DB_USER}:${PASSWORD}@localhost:27017?authMechanism=DEFAULT&authSource=db';`

in my opinion it is also more easy to read

hope it helps =)

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding your user and password with this:

```
function percentEncode(string) {
  let encoded = '';
  string.split('').forEach(function(char) {
    encoded += '%' + char.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase();
  });
  return encoded;
}
```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1

Here's where I got the idea from: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/issues/499

Good Luck =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `URL encoding` ,the default `ASCII` code for `@` is `%40`. See link [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)

```
const url = 'mongodb://roots:something%40@localhost:27017?authMechanism=DEFAULT&authSource=db';
```